# Using #Required keyword in XML with enumerated values

Tags: xml, dtd

Can i use #Required keyword in XML with enumerated value list?

like ,

```
<!ATTLIST item type CDATA (offer|request) "offer" #REQUIRED>
```

Thanks..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found it :)
its not possible :)
we can't use #required keyword with enumerated value lists in XML like

```
<!ATTLIST item type CDATA (offer|request) "offer" #REQUIRED>
```

I checked it with validator and it gives error with #REQUIRED ..

Comment: Please add your solution as part of your answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 2):

it's fine to have such combination like:

```
<!ATTLIST item type (offer|request) #REQUIRED>
```

But I'm not sure about CDATA definition in case of choice and also combination of default value and required is not ok. Try http://www.validome.org/grammar/validate/

Regards

JK.

Answer (score 2):

No.

According to the [XML Specification Attribute List Declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#attdecls) you can declare atributes as

```
<!ATTLIST' element-name attribute-definitions* >
```

where `attribute-definitions` has the format

```
attribute-name attribute-type default-declaration
```

The attribute-type can be *one* of

- `CDATA`
- `ID`
- `IDREF`
- `IDREFS`
- `ENTITY`
- `ENTITIES`
- `NMTOKEN`
- `NMTOKENS` *or*
- An enumeration of different NMTOKENS within parentheses separated by `|`.
  Ex: `( token1 | token2 | token3 )`.

There are no other options.

Additionally, `default-declaration` allows *one* of the values:

- `#REQUIRED`
- `#IMPLIED`
- `#FIXED "fixed value"`
- `"default value"`

There are also no other options. So if you have `CDATA`, you can't have `(offer|request)`, and if you have `#REQUIRED` you can't have `#REQUIRED "offer"` or `"offer" #REQUIRED` as you wrote. Some valid options, depending on what you want, are:

```
<!ATTLIST item type (offer|request) "request">
<!ATTLIST item type (offer|request) #REQUIRED>
<!ATTLIST item type CDATA "offer">
<!ATTLIST item type CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

Comment: Comprehensive answer. :)